# Flatsome Theme: how to stop adding dynamic ID on Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

Flatsome is a really good theme, although there are some things i am not quite happy with, for example, the annoying dynamic IDs, i am giving the element a class which i am going to use to style  but the id is already printed with some default padding. For example: A section has a fixed padding of 30 px top and bottom... which i can only override by using important because is bein printed on the index file.... so has anyone came up with a clean solution to this?

thanks a lot in advance

i am creating a new page with a custom css so i need the most liberty to style